# ls shows file, but when trying to read it is says it doesn't exist

Tags: linux, mount, fedora, cifs

I have a CIFS mount on my PC and the `ls` command shows me a certain file is there:

```
[bf@localhost dirX]$ ls -la
total 4096
drwxr-xr-x. 2 bf bf      0 20 okt 09:12 .
drwxr-xr-x. 2 bf bf      0  5 sep 11:05 ..
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 bf bf    880 19 okt 17:44 WeirdFile
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 bf bf    880 19 okt 17:44 GoodFile
```

However, when trying to read from it (or save to it), it says the file doesn't exist:

```
[bf@localhost dirX]$ cat WeirdFile
cat: WeirdFile: No such file or directory
```

Trying to `cat GoodFile` does work.

I am having trouble with CIFS anyway since moving to Fedora 26 and having to force to version 2.1 in fstab. Main problem is bad performance (slow!), but this is just plain weird.

**Update** when remounting the share, the file is gone.

Comment: Have you tried: `more *WeirdFile*` ?

Answer (score 3):

A possible reason that that Weirdfile isn't really using ASCII characters in the name. If this is the case, if you type the file name it doesn't work, but if you use copy/paste it does (it can also work with command completion, depending on where the non-Ascii character is).

There are two possibilities for non-ASCII characters:

- the non-ASCII character has a glyph which is identical to one in the latin alphabet (Cyrillic 'a', 'o', 'e' are typical)
- the non-ASCII character is not visible (+U200B, non-breaking-zero-width-space, for instance).

Besides the copy/paste v.s. retype difference:

- if you do `ls suspisciousfile | wc -c`, with all-ASCII the `wc` output will be just one more byte than you can count characters in the file name (due to final linefeed), if there are non-ASCII characters it will be longer.
- with `hexdump`: `ls suspisciousfile | hexdump -C` will make any non-ASCII characters very obvious. Example with a specially crafted `filе` (where the final `е` is actually a Cyrillic character):

[image]

- with `uniname` from package `uniutils`. This utility dumps a string, character by character. For instance with the same crafted `filе`:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: I typed the filename using tab completion. And tried `hexdump`, nothing weird there.

Answer (score 0):

I had a log file from a vendor app that really threw me off.

Turns out its file name ended with a space.

Try `cat *WeirdFile*` to see if there's any non-printing chars